# Textarea return value is always null

Tags: javascript, textarea

I am trying to get the users input from a textarea into my javascript

```js
function validateMessage() {
  var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  window.alert(message);
}
```

```html
<label>Message:</label>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="message">Foo</textarea><button onclick="validateMessage()">Validate message</button>
```

Browsers console keeps giving me this message

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Learn More] 
>   contact.js:51:14

Line 51 is the actual line in my JavaScript.
I have read solutions where most people say to use the .value
But as you can see it returns null.
I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the function **after** the page (or at least that element) has loaded?

Comment: You have another question with good answers without an accepted answer. This site lives because of that, so I recommend you to have a good ratio of questions with accepted answers as people will notice that you don't accept answers, so they won't put effort into helping you.

Comment: Yes the function is being call. I have tested . Also if the function was not called it would not bring up the error

Comment: @Ricky Not talking about the function being called. Talking about the function being called AFTER (notice the after in bold) the page has loaded.

Comment: Voting to close as the code as posted works, provided the function is called after the textarea exists.

Comment: Thanks that worked. it was the flow

Answer (score 1):

The error is not that textarea return value is null, but that `getElementById` is null, meaning that there's no element with id `message`.

As a **tip**, learn to understand the errors. Read them carefully understanding each word.

Comment: Whitespace in the markup has nothing to do with the OP's issue. The opening tag can be `<textarea rows="5"cols="50"id="message">`.

Comment: @RobG Oh, I'm used to "whitespaces define the words". Didn't know that HTML don't need whitespaces.

Comment: @RobG Just tested and yes, that's fine. Good to know.

Comment: If I type something in the texarea then the getElementById("message") is not null as there is actual data in the id="message". If you have a look at my html code there is an element with id message. I have also tried the space betwean cols="50" and id="message" still gives me the error.

Comment: @Ricky, you got it wrong.`getElementById("message")` don't returns the value. Returns the `textarea` element, where you later access  the `.value` property to get the value BUT if `getElementById("message")` returns null, then you cannot access the `.value` property of a null. As you can see, the error says that `getElementById("message")` returns null, not that `.value` returns null. Read this carefully and try to understand it. The only reason that `getElementById` returns null is that the element don't exists on the webpage at the moment of the call.

Comment: Remember that webpages have a "flow", where code is run before or after the page render, depending on its disposition, events and such.

Comment: I doubt that the code is as simple as you put. You can share a fiddle or something where we can take a look and find out what is truly happening. Maybe something that you think that is not important is the key of the problem.

Comment: Ok , but why does it work if a use input="text". so I am calling at at the same time I would be calling the textarea and it works . But I unfortanly need teaxarea as I need multipule rows.

Comment: thanks its working now. Had to do with when the eventListner was running